# Oracle SQL: How to generate a cricket match point table with details such as win count, lost count etc?

Tags: sql, oracle

I faced this question in an interview. I had to get points earned , win count, lost count, match drawn count for a team. My query gives me correct result but i am looking for a way to shoterned the query. Any help ?

Certain Conditions i Considered in my query are:

```
1. If a team wins i am allocating 3 as match point and 2 if a team loses
2. If the match is a tie (when winner is null) i am awarding 1 point to each team.
```

DDL and DML:

```
create table match_t(team1 varchar(20),team2 varchar(20),Winner varchar(20));

insert into match_t values('India','Pakistan','India');
insert into match_t values('India','Srilanka','India');
insert into match_t values('Srilanka','Pakistan','Pakistan');
insert into match_t values('Srilanka','India','Srilanka');
insert into match_t values('Pakistan','Srilanka','Srilanka');
insert into match_t values('Pakistan','India','India');
insert into match_t values('India','Srilanka','India');
insert into match_t values('Pakistan','India',null);
insert into match_t values('Srilanka','Pakistan',null);
Commit;
```

My answer to the problem:

```
with abc as(
select team1 as host,team2 as guest,case when team1=winner
then 1 else 0 end as host_w,
case when team2 = winner
then 1 else 0 end as guest_w  
 from match_t), bac as(
 select host,3 as m_point,1 as host_win,0 as guest_win,0 as match_d from abc where host_w > guest_w
 union all
 select guest,3 as m_point,0 as host_win,1 as guest_win,0 as match_d from abc where host_w < guest_w
union all
select guest,2 as m_point,0 as host_win,0 as guest_win,0 as match_d from abc where host_w > guest_w
 union all
 select host,2 as m_point,0 as host_win,0 as guest_win,0 as match_d from abc where host_w < guest_w
 union all
 select host,1 as m_point,0 as host_win,0 as guest_win, 1 as match_d from abc where host_w = guest_w
 union all
 select guest,1 as m_point,0 as host_win,0 as guest_win, 1 as match_d from abc where host_w = guest_w
 ),
 cad as(
 select host as team,sum(m_point) as match_p,sum(host_win+guest_win) as win_c,
sum(match_d)  as match_d_c 
 from bac group by host),
 dac as(select sum(lost_c) as lost_c,team from (select count(*) as lost_c,host as team from abc where host_w=0 and guest_w <> 0
 group by host
 union all
 select count(*) as lost_c,guest as team from abc where guest_w=0 and host_w <> 0
 group by guest) group by team)
  select a.team,a.match_p,a.win_c,b.lost_c,a.match_d_c,a.win_c+b.lost_c+a.match_d_c as no_match from cad a, dac b where a.team=b.team
```

It gives me correct result(refer below) . But I am looking for a way how easily i can get it without writing such long code

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using `union all`, but the query would simply be:

```
select team, sum(is_win) as num_wins, sum(is_loss) as num_losses, sum(is_tie) as num_ties
from ((select team1 as team,
               (case when winner = team1 then 1 else 0 end) as is_win,
               (case when winner = team2 then 1 else 0 end) as is_loss,
               (case when winner is null then 1 else 0 end) as is_tie
        from match_t
       ) union all
       (select team2,
               (case when winner = team2 then 1 else 0 end) as is_win,
               (case when winner = team1 then 1 else 0 end) as is_loss,
               (case when winner is null then 1 else 0 end) as is_tie
        from match_t
       )
      ) t
group by team;
```

I'm a bit surprised at how complicated the other answers are.  The idea is pretty simple.  For each team in the match you want flags indicating whether the game was a win, loss, or tie.  You then want to aggregate these flags over all the teams.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it using `union all` to get team and the corresponding result into a column and then using a `group by` to get all the wins,losses,ties and total points.

```
select team
,count(*) as num_matches
,sum(points) as total_points
,sum(case when result='Win' then 1 else 0 end) as num_wins
,sum(case when result='Lose' then 1 else 0 end) as num_losses
,sum(case when result='Tie' then 1 else 0 end) as num_ties
from (select winner as team,3 as points,'Win' as result
      from match_t
      where winner is not null
      union all 
      select case when winner = least(team1,team2) then greatest(team1,team2) else least(team1,team2) end,2,'Lose'
      from match_t
      where winner is not null
      union all
      select team1,1,'Tie'
      from match_t
      where winner is null
      union all
      select team2,1,'Tie'
      from match_t
      where winner is null
     ) t
group by team
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggravated function with once `UNION ALL` to let the code clear.

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table match_t(team1 varchar(20),team2 varchar(20),Winner varchar(20));

insert into match_t values('India','Pakistan','India');
insert into match_t values('India','Srilanka','India');
insert into match_t values('Srilanka','Pakistan','Pakistan');
insert into match_t values('Srilanka','India','Srilanka');
insert into match_t values('Pakistan','Srilanka','Srilanka');
insert into match_t values('Pakistan','India','India');
insert into match_t values('India','Srilanka','India');
insert into match_t values('Pakistan','India',null);
insert into match_t values('Srilanka','Pakistan',null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 'Srilanka' Team,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Winner = 'Srilanka' AND (team1 = 'Srilanka' or team2='Srilanka') then 3 
                 WHEN Winner IS NULL  AND (team1 = 'Srilanka' or team2='Srilanka') THEN 1 
                 WHEN team1 = 'Srilanka' or team2='Srilanka' THEN 2 END
           )MATCH_P,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner = 'Srilanka'  THEN 1 END) WIN_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner <> 'Srilanka'AND (team1 = 'Srilanka' or team2='Srilanka') THEN 1 END) LOST_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner IS NULL AND (team1 = 'Srilanka' or team2='Srilanka') THEN 1 END) MATCH_D_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  (team1 = 'Srilanka' or team2='Srilanka') THEN 1 END) NO_MATCH
FROM match_t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pakistan' Team,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Winner = 'Pakistan' AND (team1 = 'Pakistan' or team2='Pakistan') then 3 
                 WHEN Winner IS NULL  AND (team1 = 'Pakistan' or team2='Pakistan') THEN 1 
                 WHEN team1 = 'Pakistan' or team2='Pakistan' THEN 2 END
           )MATCH_P,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner = 'Pakistan'  THEN 1 END) WIN_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner <> 'Pakistan'AND (team1 = 'Pakistan' or team2='Pakistan') THEN 1 END) LOST_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner IS NULL AND (team1 = 'Pakistan' or team2='Pakistan') THEN 1 END) MATCH_D_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  (team1 = 'Pakistan' or team2='Pakistan') THEN 1 END) NO_MATCH
FROM match_t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'India' Team,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Winner = 'India' AND (team1 = 'India' or team2='India') then 3 
                 WHEN Winner IS NULL  AND (team1 = 'India' or team2='India') THEN 1 
                 WHEN team1 = 'India' or team2='India' THEN 2 END
           )MATCH_P,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner = 'India'  THEN 1 END) WIN_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner <> 'India'AND (team1 = 'India' or team2='India') THEN 1 END) LOST_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  Winner IS NULL AND (team1 = 'India' or team2='India') THEN 1 END) MATCH_D_C,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  (team1 = 'India' or team2='India') THEN 1 END) NO_MATCH
FROM match_t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b25c/5/0)**:

```
|     TEAM | MATCH_P | WIN_C | LOST_C | MATCH_D_C | NO_MATCH |
|----------|---------|-------|--------|-----------|----------|
| Srilanka |      13 |     2 |      3 |         1 |        6 |
| Pakistan |      11 |     1 |      3 |         2 |        6 |
|    India |      15 |     4 |      1 |         1 |        6 |
```

Comment: This is correct but i was looking for a way not hardcode the value. The Answer from Vamsi solves the purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can opt for using unpivot to get tou the results you want.

```
with data
  as (select row_number() over(order by 1) as rnk
            ,t.team1
            ,t.team2
            ,t.winner
            ,case when t.winner is not null then 
                  case when t.team1 <> t.winner then t.team1
                       else t.team2
                  end
             end as loser
            ,case when t.winner is null then t.team1 end tie1
            ,case when t.winner is null then t.team2 end tie2
       from match_t t
       )
  ,folded_data
   as (select *
         from data
       unpivot(val for x in (winner
                            ,loser
                            ,tie1
                            ,tie2
                             )
               )t
      )
 select val
        ,sum(case when x='WINNER' then 3
                  when x='LOSER'  then 2
                  when x in ('TIE1','TIE2') then 1
              end) as tot_points
        ,count(rnk) as match_played   
        ,count(case when x='WINNER' then 1 end) as win_count
        ,count(case when x='LOSER' then 1 end) as loser_count
        ,count(case when x in('TIE1','TIE2') then 1 end) as tie_count
   from folded_data
 group by val
```

Here is a dbfiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0aabf7d1f19ecd010f53903b56427959